# How to post a Facebook Photo having 2 space characters using Facebook PHP SDK?

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, character, space

I wanted to upload a photo to FB using the FB PHP SDK that has 2 space characters side by side but apparently with HTML only one space character is displayed.  Using Javascript SDK on feed posts, I can do this using " " + "&nbsp;", but if I submit the photo message with the PHP SDK, it comes out with the exact characters of " " (&nbsp; in HTML) at the result.

Answer (score 0):

> Using Javascript SDK on feed posts, I can do this using " " + "&nbsp;", but if I submit the photo message with the PHP SDK, it comes out with the exact characters of " " (&nbsp; in HTML) at the result.

That’s quite logical – because your JavaScript is in an HTML document, where `&nbsp;` gets replaced with an actual non-breaking space *character* at the time of parsing – your PHP code however is not parsed as HTML, and therefor &nbsp; is not replaced by anything, but just stands for the characters &, n, b, s, p, ; in sequence.

You could try using the unicode representation of a non-breaking space, which is 0xA0 or 160 in decimal – and see whether Facebook accepts that or replaces it with a normal space. (But since your JavaScript post essentially comes down to the same thing, I think it should work.)

```
utf8_encode(chr(160))
```

will give you a correctly UTF-8 encoded non-breaking space character in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `urlencode($urlPath);` . This should transform your string in an url-friendly one.